# react-native-admob: AdMobBanner can't click in ios

Tags: android, ios, react-native, admob

I using react-native 0.39.2, react-native-admob ^1.1.5 and my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
Platform
} from "react-native";

import {AdMobBanner} from 'react-native-admob';
export default class extends React.Component {
   render() {
      if ((Platform.OS === 'ios'))
          return (
              <AdMobBanner style={{height: 50}}
                             adUnitID="adUnitId-ios"
                             testDeviceID="EMULATOR"/>
          );
      else return (
<AdMobBanner adUnitID="adUnitID-android"
                     testDeviceID="EMULATOR"/>
      );
   }
}
```

But just Android can click in AdMobBanner, IOS can't.

Comment: This is probably best answered from the react-native-admob repository on github

Comment: This PR fixed the issue for me: https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/pull/70